# What is making Visual Studio hang and how can I prevent it?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm working on a solution in Visual Studio (v10.0.30319.1) which contains 8 C# projects (WPF Application and Class Libraries).  I've been working on this solution for several months, but yesterday I started having problems with Visual Studio hanging for some time when starting and stopping my app in the debug environment.

I first notice it when I stop the application and VS hangs for around 5 seconds.  I then press F5 to start again and it takes 5-10 seconds to start.  Then I stop the application and it takes about 10 seconds to stop.  The problem subsequently worsens until I reboot the computer (I'm not sure if restarting VS is sufficient - I will test and update the question when it happens again).

Once the computer has been restarted, I cannot replicate the problem, but I know it will creep up on me again today.

While the problem is happening, one of the cores is at 100% usage.  Memory usage for devenv.exe is normal at a bit over 200MB, and not increasing.

The computer is quite powerful and everything else is working correctly so I'm sure it's not a resource issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you update VS2010 with Service Pack 1?

[Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 Download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5)

Be warned, although the page says it's only an 800 KB download, what is actually downloaded is a downloader that downloads over 800 MB of patches. (That's a lot of "downloads" :P)

Comment: Thanks - I applied SP1 last week and have not had the problem since - I presume this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your solution user option files i.e. {SolutionName}.suo and {SolutionName}.docstates.suo
It worked for me, before doing that I tried @Casey solution but it didn't work.

so first try deleting files, if it do not work then update VS2010 and then delete files again.